How to use fields to output to a file path in fluent-bit?
I am using fluent-bit to accept logs in JSON format, and want to write these to files in a path based on the log content.
Example log (simplified)
{timestamp:"2024-07-01T01:01:01", source:"a", data:"much text"}

I want to append this log to the file /var/log/system/a/2024/07/01/system.log
I have tried using fields in the OUTPUT file definition, but they are not expanded.
I have now tried overriding the Tag (which is the default value for the file in the output stanza), but this also fails because the field names are apparently incorrectly terminated - it seems to want a . as the terminator?
[FILTER]
  name           rewrite_tag
  match          system
  rule           $timestamp ^(....)-(..)-(..)T system/$source/$1/$2/$3/system.log false
[OUTPUT]
    name    file
    format  plain
    match   system/*
    path    /var/log/
    mkdir   true

Specifying the fields as ${source} does not help as it then seems to think it is an Environment variable instead.
I can use this, which works, but all the files end up in the same directory, which becomes too crowded:
  rule           $timestamp ^(....-..-..)T system/$source.$1.system.log false

I've tried this (which sort-of works!), but it results in the written file being /var/log/system/a./2024./07./01./system.log which is ugly as there is a trailing . on each path component:
  rule           $timestamp ^(....)-(..)-(..)T system/$source./$1./$2./$3./system.log false

Does anyone have a workable solution to how this can be done?  It seems to be a pretty common requirement to output to different files not in the same directory but so far I've not found a way to achieve it.  A lua filter can't modify the Tag or else I'd use that.

I don't think fluentbit support slashes in tags, as said in their docs: https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/filters/rewrite-tag#new-tag. Only ,-. are supported.
Record accessor in file output is not supported either: https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/issues/7109
Maybe you can use vector instead. A sample config that does what you want:
[sources.demo]
type = "demo_logs"
format = "shuffle"
lines = [ '{"timestamp":"2024-07-01T01:01:01", "source":"a", "data":"much text"}' ]

[transforms.parse_date]
type = "remap"
inputs = ["demo"]
source = '''
# Convert log to a VRL object
# `%` set parsed fields in log event metadata
%parsed_json = object!(parse_json!(.message))
%parsed_date = parse_regex!(%parsed_json.timestamp, r'^(?P<year>\d{4})-(?P<month>\d{2})-(?P<day>\d{2})T')
'''

[sinks.logfile]
type = "file"
inputs = ["parse_date"]
path = "/var/log/system/{{ %parsed_json.source }}/{{ %parsed_date.year }}/{{ %parsed_date.month }}/{{ %parsed_date.day }}/system.log"
encoding.codec = "text"

Result:
test@test /t/tmp.428DsETMPf> tree logs/
logs/
└── system
    └── a
        └── 2024
            └── 07
                └── 01
                    └── system.log

6 directories, 1 file
test@test /t/tmp.428DsETMPf> tail logs/system/a/2024/07/01/system.log
{"timestamp":"2024-07-01T01:01:01", "source":"a", "data":"much text"}
{"timestamp":"2024-07-01T01:01:01", "source":"a", "data":"much text"}
{"timestamp":"2024-07-01T01:01:01", "source":"a", "data":"much text"}
{"timestamp":"2024-07-01T01:01:01", "source":"a", "data":"much text"}
{"timestamp":"2024-07-01T01:01:01", "source":"a", "data":"much text"}
{"timestamp":"2024-07-01T01:01:01", "source":"a", "data":"much text"}
{"timestamp":"2024-07-01T01:01:01", "source":"a", "data":"much text"}
{"timestamp":"2024-07-01T01:01:01", "source":"a", "data":"much text"}
{"timestamp":"2024-07-01T01:01:01", "source":"a", "data":"much text"}
{"timestamp":"2024-07-01T01:01:01", "source":"a", "data":"much text"}


Sure there are several other software (such as rsyslog) that can do it, but that is not a solution to this question, I need to make this work with fluent-bit.
